# Angular 4 - Display Current Navigation from SharePoint on website

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint

I created new SharePoint Current Navigation - Share Point Academy -> Site Settings -> Navigation -> Structural Navigation: Editing and Sorting

and now I see that navigation on the left sidebar and that's ok, but I don't know how to display that navigation as dropdown on my website...

[image]

For example, I have these two dropdown (Reiseplanung and Administration), and dropdown menu items as you can see on the image. I need to create two Bootstrap dropdown menu items with appropriate dropdown submenu items.

Is there any way to do that? Every help is appreciated

**navBar.component.html**

```
<div class="col-sm-12 navbar-wrapper">
<div class="icon">
<a href="#" (click)="goBack()">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
</div>
<div class="icon">
<a href="#" (click)="openCalendar()">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
</div>
<div class="icon">
<a href="#" (click)="travelRequestsList()">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
</div>
<div class="icon">
<a href="#" (click)="newtravelRequest()">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
</div>
<div class="btn-group" dropdown> <-- **Dropdown from SharePoint should be here**
    <button dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
        Navigation <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li role="menuitem">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        </li>
        <li role="menuitem">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        </li>
        <li role="menuitem">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </li>
        <li role="menuitem">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**navBar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

  declare var _spPageContextInfo;

   @Component({
    selector: 'rp-navbar',
    templateUrl: './navBar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./navBar.component.css'],
    providers: []
  })
  export class NavBarComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor() { }

   /**
   * Component is initialized. (Angular lifecycle hook)
   */
   ngOnInit() {

   }

   /**
    * Back to the last accessed page.
    */
   goBack() {
      window.history.back();
   }

  /**
   * Back to Landing Page (Calendar)
   */
   openCalendar() {
     window.location.href = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + 
    "/SiteAssets/Pages/home.aspx#/home";
  }

 /**
  * Back to list of my travel requests
  */
  travelRequestsList() {
     window.location.href = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + 
  "/SiteAssets/Pages/listview.aspx#/listview";
 }

/**
 * Create new travel request
 */
 newtravelRequest() {
     window.location.href = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + 
  "/SiteAssets/Pages/edit.aspx#/edit";
  }
}
```

**navBar.component.css**

```
.navbar-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background: #eee;
    padding-top: 11px;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
    margin: 20px 0px 50px;
  }

.icon {
   display: inline-block;
   font-size: 20px;
   margin-right: 25px;
 }

 .icon a {
   color: #000000;
  }

 .icon:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
  }
```

Comment: Of course, there is a way to do that. Post your code (HTML + css) inside your question.

Comment: I just updated my question, please see. Thank you

Comment: You seem to be using Bootstrap 3, is that correct?

Comment: Yes @WebDevBooster, that's correct